# Check-in to some code to more than one branch

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, checkin

I am using TFS2012 express. I have a project which has two branches.These two branches have similar file and code. Actually one is release code(one which i gave to customers) and another is testing code. I always change code in testing code branch. So sometime i need to checkin this changes to both the branch. Also some changes i don't want to check-in to both and only to testing code branch. So how i can do it in tfs? Problem is how to checkin only certain changes to both branch and some changes to only one branch?

Comment: You can always check in the changes to testing branch. If you need certain changes in the release branch as well, you can use Merge command to do that.

Comment: @Rachel Merge will merge all changes from one branch to another and it will make both branch same. But in my case i want to checkin only some changes to both the branch. Some change will be checkin to only one branch.

Comment: When you do Merge, you can choose "Selected change sets" instead of All changes.

Comment: @Rachel Works fine. But there is one problem, when change are in adjacent lines . If change set 10 contains changes is in code let us say line number 100 and changeset 11 contain changes in line number 101. Then while merging only changeset 11 conflicts is shown.It shows those 100,101 line numbers.Now how can i select only line 101 to checkin which is in changeset 11. there is option to tick in merge tool.It selects both line not single line.Please help

Comment: The result panel at the bottom of merge tool is editable. So you can always choose/make the changes you like.

Comment: @Rachel worked fine. I think you can post it answer so that that i can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always check in the changes to testing branch. If you need certain changes in the release branch as well, you can use Merge command to do that.

When you do Merge, you can choose "Selected change sets" instead of All changes. When resolving conflicts in mergetool, you can choose/make the changes you like in the result panel at the bottom which is editable.