# How to link two files with same name in two different folders in tfs

Tags: tfs

I am using 2013 tfs, in which i have created normal folders where i keep my files to track changes made by different users.

Now i want to keep same file in two folders and want changes done from one place to be reflected at all places where ever i have kept(linked) the file in different folders.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that once a file changed, another file will be also updated accordingly?

You can sync the files with merge:

1. Convert the folders to Branches,
2. Check in the changes to one branch
3. Merge the changes from one branch to another

See [Merge folders and files](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/merge-folders-files) and [Merge Command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/merge-command) for details.

You can also reference below similar threads:

- [TFS: Overwrite a branch with another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092863/tfs-overwrite-a-branch-with-another/2094439#2094439)
- [Check-in to some code to more than one branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511386/check-in-to-some-code-to-more-than-one-branch)

Comment: @user3129097 Have you resolved the issue by above workaround? Any udpate?